# Firebase read addValueEventListener onDataChange value null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to read some data from the Firebase Database the ondatachange is getting the correct data but I can't seem to get the data out of there.

I have a few log commands:

> Log.d("Tag","name: "+product.getName());

Only the the one inside onDataChange is showing the value, inside onCreate and onCreateView it gives me Null Pointer Error

I realize now it's because onDataChange is Asynchronous where can I get some info on the proper way of dealing with this?

Thanks!

```
public class ProductDetailFragment extends Fragment {
private EventBus eventBus = EventBus.getDefault();
private String productPushID;
private ValueEventListener valueEventListener;
private DatabaseReference prodIDRef;
private Product product;
private TextView tvProductSKU;
private TextView tvProductName;

public ProductDetailFragment(){

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ProductClickedEvent productClickedEvent = eventBus.getStickyEvent(ProductClickedEvent.class);
    if(productClickedEvent != null) {
        eventBus.removeStickyEvent(productClickedEvent);
        productPushID = productClickedEvent.getProductPushID();
    }

    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference prodRef = rootRef.child("products");
    prodIDRef = prodRef.child(productPushID);
    valueEventListener = prodIDRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Product sProduct = dataSnapshot.getValue(Product.class);
            if (sProduct == null) {
                getActivity().finish();
                return;
            }
            product= sProduct;
            Log.d("onDataChange","name: "+product.getName());
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    //Log.d("onCreate","name: "+product.getName());
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context){
    super.onAttach(context);
    eventBus.register(this);
}

@Subscribe(sticky = true, threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onEvent(ProductClickedEvent productClickedEvent) {
    Log.d("SubScribe",productClickedEvent.getProductPushID());
    productPushID = productClickedEvent.getProductPushID();
}

@Override
public void onDetach(){
    super.onDetach();
    eventBus.unregister(this);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    prodIDRef.removeEventListener(valueEventListener);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //Log.d("onCreateView","name: "+product.getName());

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_product_detail, container, false);

    tvProductSKU = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvProductSKU);
    tvProductName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvProductName);

    tvProductSKU.setText("SKU: " + product.getSKU());
    tvProductName.setText("Name: " + product.getName());
    return view;
}
}
```

Comment: After some hours I realized that the OnDataChange returns after onCreateView is already called. So it does not wait until the the data is retrieved from FireBase. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: As you said.. why don't you put your code inside the onDataChange() ?

It should be the only way since it translates to "When there is a datachange, do this.."

This part of your code (onDataChange) might take a while in cases that you have no fast internet or so.. therefore the rest of the code (onCreateView) will be executed in the meanwhile.

The whole thing happens to make sure your GUI will not be locked (look like your app crashed) in cases that you need to gather data on your phone but in the meanwhile you need to use your phone..

Comment: Hi @user2399432 realize now that what I was doing does not make sense. You are totally right! Moved tvProductSKU.setText("SKU: " + product.getSKU()); tvProductName.setText("Name: " + product.getName()); Now I'm good!

Comment: I posted my comment as answer in case you want to select it as an accepted aswer. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said.. why don't you put your code inside the onDataChange() ? It should be the only way since it translates to "When there is a datachange, do this.."

This part of your code (onDataChange) might take a while in cases that you have no fast internet or so.. therefore the rest of the code (onCreateView) will be executed in the meanwhile.

The whole thing happens to make sure your GUI will not be locked (look like your app crashed) in cases that you need to gather data on your phone but in the meanwhile you need to use your phone..